# How to Rename an Environment in PostMan?

Tags: postman

I duplicated an environment in PostMan, but I can't figure out how to rename it. How to rename an environment in PostMan?

I tried clicking everything on the UI, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Select your environment from the available environments, then click on the eye button on selected environment, edit option should appears there. then edit with a new name.

Comment: I got it... my screen is large and the pencil appears aligned to the right, so I wasn't seeing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

click on copy,  rename, update.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was focused on the right side of the screen, but actually there is a navigation command at the left where you can easily manage Environments.

[image: Right side of Postman]

Comment: In newer versions of Postman, this is the way to go. The pencil icon described in other answers no longer exists. Up-and downvoting accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Open the environment.

Hover the mouse over the name. There will appear the pencil icon:

[image]

Click it and replace a name with whatever you want